# How can I read resource file from within annotation processor?

Tags: java, annotations

From within annotation processor (one that is derived from AbstractProcessor) I can read content of particular file in package this way:

```
processingEnv.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH, "", <path-to-file>);
```

My goal is to read file from `src/main/resources` folder for the class within `src/main/java` which contains an annotated method and I'm failing to do that.

What I've tried so far:

- `element.getEnclosingElement().getClass().getResource(<resource-name>)`;
- `element.getEnclosingElement().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(<resource-name>)`;

It feels like I'm missing something pretty simple yet, if you ask me, quite poorly documented.